# Function does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I am writing a function that should validate an email and a password from a pop up box. If the entered email and password are correct all goes fine. But if the email or password are wrong nothing happens (the function should show a message "User does not exists").

I need some expert help with it since half day efforts is not brining any results. Thank you.

```
function loginonly(frmId,hidDiv,displyDiv,errorDiv,type) {

        var msgid = document.getElementById('msgid').value;
        var gen =   jQuery.noConflict();
        gen.post(
            MYSURL+'ajaxphp/ajaxvalidation.php?act=userLogin2', 
            gen('#'+frmId).serialize(),             
            function(data){
                dataarr=data.split('#');
                gen('#sesschk').val(dataarr[0]);
                gen('#sesschk2').val(dataarr[2]);                               
                if(dataarr[1] == 1){                    
                    gen('#'+hidDiv).html('');
                    gen('#'+displyDiv).css('display','block');                  
                    if(type == 'w'){                
                        gen('#cboxClose').click();                      
                    }       
                }else if(dataarr[1] == 2){
                    gen('#'+errorDiv).html('');
                    gen('#'+errorDiv).html('<div class="notification error png_bg top10" style="width:250px; font-family:calibri;" ><img src='+MYSURL+'images/icons/cross_circle.png>&nbsp; User does not exists.</div>');
                }               
            }
        );
        return false;}
```

Comment: is there a typo error? missing closing brace of the function after  return false;

Comment: What is data returning in your response?
Try doing a `console.log(data)` to see what is coming back.

Comment: the `}` is there I just forgot to paste it. question corrected.

Comment: Examine the response using your browser’s debugging tools.

Comment: Maybe server returns 403 if user is invalid then success callback wont be execute.